# UEFI and Puppy Linux

Tags: boot, live-usb, uefi, puppy-linux

I recently installed Puppy Linux on a USB stick using the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), but I have not being able to boot from it. My notebook came with Windows 8 and had the secure boot activated at UEFI. I disabled the secure boot option, but I am still not able to boot from the USB stick (it is not being shown in the list of bootable devices).

Interestingly, a live USB with certain Linux distros are recognized on my computer, such as Linux Mint Cinnamon and Ubuntu. But others, such as Puppy, Zorin, Elementary OS and Mint MATE are not working.

Basically all advice I found online is to disable the secure boot option, which I already did. Is there anything else I can do in order to boot from my usb stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a full shutdown, because you use Windows 8.
Maybe you must disable the hybrid boot: http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/

Type in cmd:
`shutdown /s /t 0`

Also look at this:
http://puppylinux.org/wikka/UEFI

Comment: hmm, I searched that link and it doesn't mention UEFI nor EFI at all. I had no problems installing Puppy on a USB stick, my problem was to make my UEFI boot recognize it and boot from it.

Comment: You need a full shutdown, because you use Windows 8. You must disable the hybrid boot: http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. Please bear in mind that answers should stand on its own, which is why posting just a link is bad. Please put the relevant part here. Also if you have doubts if your approach answers the question, consider adding a comment to clarify the issue and then answer the question.